# How to test <script>alert("XSSTest")</script>

Tags: testing, penetration-testing, security-testing

I need to pass (alert("XSSTest")) this string in all the field to test-penetration testing. even i dont have much idea about this. Presently am doing this entering this text/script manually to each and every field of my web application. Can any one suggest me is there is any tool which can ease this task. I even heard there are many plugin for FF browser available for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options to automate XSS testing. 
You can use free and commercial softwares to acheive this. I listed some popular tools below:

**Commercial (there may be a trial version)**

- [NetSparker](https://www.netsparker.com/)
- [Acunetix](https://www.acunetix.com/)
- [IBM AppScan](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/appscan/)

**Freeware**

- [Xenotix](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Xenotix_XSS_Exploit_Framework)
- [BurpSuite](https://portswigger.net/burp/download.html)
- [ZedProxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project)
- [x5s](https://xss.codeplex.com/)

**Mozilla Firefox AddOn:**

- [XSS Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xss-me/?src=search)

Now bear in mind that if you have the source code of the application that you want to test, you may do also static code analysis. This also depends on the technology you are using. Find below some tools for this:

- [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
- [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)
- [IBM AppScan (Source)](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/products/appscan/source/)

Of course the lists may continue for many more other tools.